# Scene created in Sprite kit level editor is not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to do this for a while. I have a main scene for a game named `PlayScene`. I have a pause button there. When player is tapping that button I want to load another scene, named PauseScene. For visualy creating that scene I use Sprite kit level editor. So I have two files `PauseScene.swift`and `PauseScene.sks`. But .sks content ( just a background for now) isn't unarchiving. I don't really know where could I make a mistake.
So this is my transition via pause button, located in `PlayScene`

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.pause {
            var scene = PauseScene(size: self.size)
            scene.paused = true
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

And this is what I have in `PauseScene.swift`:

```
class PauseScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.initPauseScene()
}
func initPauseScene() {

}
```

}

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009957/do-i-need-to-create-a-new-spritekit-level-editor-file-for-every-new-swift-file) and it's not working very well. However [that tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_Swift_Sprite_Kit_Level_Editor_Game_Tutorial) is closest I could get with my problem. It's not crushing and isn't showing any errors, but when I tap pause button it's transitioning to that scene without my background, just standard grey scene. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685733/how-do-i-link-a-sks-file-to-a-swift-file-in-spritekit?rq=1) answer is not working for me. First suggestion show errors and when I tried second and tap the pause – game is crushing.
  I don't know, that level editor is made for easier work but for know it just doubles it for me. I even thought that problem is in my background image maybe. But its standard .png. Why my content isn't showing up?
 So I tried to copy GameViewController default code for loading GameScene and ended up with crashing. It's not the first time I have [that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPEFP.png) while trying to unarchive this. What does it mean? I got this when i tried to replace `var scene = PauseScene(size: self.size)` with a `if let scene = PauseScene.unarchiveFromFile("PauseScene") as? PauseScene`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be transition to a grey scene due to spelling errors or the file not even being in the mainBundle. I have tested this and it works. You need to make sure that you are writing the exact name of the .sks file when loading or else you get a grey screen.

## Example

If the file is called `GameScreen.sks` and the class is called `GameScene` then if you put the class name when loading the .sks file you will get a grey screen.

```
let doors = SKTransition.doorwayWithDuration(1.0)
let archeryScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScreen")
self.view?.presentScene(archeryScene, transition: doors)
```

So if we look at the second line of code, We see that it is loading the .sks file with the name `GameScreen` opposed to the class name `GameScene`. We also abort using the file extension because the compiler know by default it is a .sks file we are searching for in the mainBundle.

If you do keep getting a grey screen, Then it may be an error in spelling or ing you GameViewController, In the SKNode Extension, Be sure to change

```
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
      if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)
        
        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
}
```

to this..

```
 extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
      if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)
        
        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as SKScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
   }
}
```

We just edited this line of code,

```
 let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
```

to this

```
 let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as SKScene
```

This will allow us to load multiple `.sks` files without any errors or crashes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and helpfulness! Unfortunately I got mad and deleted my .sks file and set up everything programmatically so I can't try it now :D But I'll definitely do this for my next scene today and will respond how it worked!

Comment: I think that I'm cursed because it's not working. I know it's my mistake somewhere. I just don't know where to look. And one more thing – let's say I position everything in `.sks` file, saved the project, locked node selection. Am I ready to go? Maybe I need to do something more to apply the changes that I made?