# Connect Game.sks to Game.swift in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I create the GameOver.sks and GameOver.swift .How can I connect them likes GameSense.sks and GameSense.swift in default sprite-kit project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the relationship between GameScene.swift and GameScene.sks files in SpriteKit template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765573/whats-the-relationship-between-gamescene-swift-and-gamescene-sks-files-in-sprit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension to unarchive an sks file.

```
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as SKNode
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

If `GameOverScene` is your SKScene and `GameOverScene.sks` is your sks file, then you can unarchive using the following code.

```
let scene = GameOver.unarchiveFromFile("GameOverScene") as GameOverScene
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with Swift 2 & Xcode 7 Beta.  Name the .sks file and the .swift file the same "GameOver.sks & GameOver.swift". Try the code in your GameScene.swift to transition to your GameOver scene to ensure its working. This is assuming your starting with the initial scene as "GameScene" in your GameViewController.swift  Also assuming you started a SpriteKit template project and added the GameOver files manually.

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene{

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView){ }

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) 
{  
sceneTransition() 
}

func sceneTransition(){
let nextScene = GameOver(size: size)
nextScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
let gameOverTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(1.0)
view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: gameOverTransition)
}
}
```