# How to spawn random images from the middle of the screen to anywhere?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I am curious if it is possible to fire images from the middle of the screen, to anywhere on the screen with a random speed.

It is important that it will be done without files containing .sks, since Xcode is crashing when I try opening that kind of files. It has to be done in a UIViewController.

I already tried subclassing a view to a SKView but without success. Looking at existing projects always uses SKViews and files containing .sks which I can not open. I hope somebody can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the images you need to "fire" should be an SKSpriteNode. They should be children of a SKScene. If you don't know how to create a SKScene or how to make the view controller present it, try creating a sample game project in Xcode - File > New Project > Game. It would create a nice sample project that would display some nice rectangles whenever you touch the screen.

Once you have your scene up and running, as well as your sprite nodes ready to fire, simply run these few lines for every node you need to fire from the middle of the screen:

```
let viewSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
let randomX = RandomInt(min: 0, max: viewSize.width)
let randomY = RandomInt(min: 0, max: viewSize.height)
let randomPosition = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)
let minDuration = 1  // Put here whatever value you feel fit for the minimum duration of flying
let maxDuration = 5  // Put here whatever value you feel fit for the maximum duration of flying
let randomDuration = TimeInterval(RandomInt(min: minDuration, max: maxDuration))
let fireAtWill = SKAction.move(to: randomPosition, duration: randomSpeed)
yourSpriteNode.runAction(fireAtWill)
```

Don't forget to replace "yourSpriteNode" with the name of the sprite node you need to fire.

Here is the RandomInt helper function:

```
func RandomInt(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max-(min-1)))) + min
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Woa, nice apps you made :) Seen your website!

Comment: Thanks! In fact only K51 and Cube Dive are based on SpriteKit, sort of my own education in Swift/SpriteKit for a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with sks files is an odd one - you may want to ask a separate question on that with more details.

You can use SpriteKit without sks files though - they are just a shortcut but everything can be done in code if you need/want to. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767425/2466193) for a discussion, an example and some useful links.